# Parent to child needs across different types of children

Tags: discussion, support

I was wondering whether there are any books that describe, perhaps even, via, videos, (if not too, personal), how different children's relational needs may differ from child to child, in terms of the care and object needs, in terms, of what needs to be given to them, and how a parent, if, in any of several ways, in as far as this depends on the child's, and, parent, must relate to the child.

This could be useful to schools and adopting parents which may have to engage themselves with the children in different ways which may not be obvious.

That is, the considerations to make may not be obvious.

Are there any books or resources, even on the web, out there, to help you deal with these sorts of issues (perhaps even written by teams of loving and caring experienced people)?

Please migrate my post to the parenting stack exchange if this post is actually appropriate there.

Thank you.